# pandasで同一idはまとめて出力し、そのうえでtimestamp順に出力したい。

Tags: python, pandas

**実行環境**
Windows 10
Python 3.X
pandas

#### データの説明

下記の元データはログをcsv化したものの一部の例になります。
こちらはid,timestampというカラムで構成されています。
timestampは昇順で並べられており、それに沿ってidが並べられています。
idは基本的にはまとまっておりますが、遅延などにより、別のidが先に割り込む形で出力されることがあり、その部分のログとなっております。

#### やりたいこと

こちらの元データを下記の**加工したいデータ**のようにsortしたいと考えております。
同一idはまとめて出力し、そのうえでtimestamp順に出力したいと考えています。
各idの先頭のtimestampでソートできればと考えております。
どのようにするとsortが可能でしょうか？

**元データ**

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z |

**加工したいデータ**

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z |
| idefs | 2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z |
| aaefsd | 2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z |
| qwerty | 2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z |

#### 試したこと

sort_valuesを使用しsortを行いました。
こちらは同じidでデータをまとめ、sortが可能ですが、idも昇順で並び替えてしまうため、
原則timestamp順で並び替えることができませんでした。

```
csv_data = '''
id,timestamp
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z
'''

df = pd.read_csv(csv_data)

df.sort_values(['id', 'timestamp'])
```

**結果**

```
        id                     timestamp
4   aaefsd  2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z
6   aaefsd  2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z
7   aaefsd  2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z
9   aaefsd  2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z
10  aaefsd  2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z
0    idefs  2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z
1    idefs  2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z
2    idefs  2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z
3    idefs  2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z
5    idefs  2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z
8   qwerty  2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z
11  qwerty  2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z
12  qwerty  2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z
13  qwerty  2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z
14  qwerty  2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z
```

**追加質問**
下記のようにidに空白がある場合に下記の加工後データにしたい場合、先ほどと同じようにグルーピング化して処理を行うことは可能でしょうか？
**元データ(csv形式)**

```
id,timestamp
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z
,2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:16.0000000Z
```

**加工後データ(csv形式)**

```
id,timestamp
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z
,2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:16.0000000Z
```

Comment: 「加工したいデータ」の id順 は 「元データ」の id の出現順でしょうか？ id のソートのルールを明記いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: はい。厳密には元データのidの先頭のtimestamp順になります。今回は元データのidのidefsの先頭のtimestampである2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Zがaaefsdの先頭のtimestampである2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Zより前に来るため、「加工したいデータ」のようにソートいたします。

Comment: `timestamp`の秒以下の部分が全て`0`だと、同じ時刻のログが複数記録される可能性が高そうですが、質問の例は簡略化のためで実際には有効なデータなのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。こちらの例は簡略化したデータで実際のデータは小数点以下の値も細かく出力されています。@kunif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> こちら、カラムがid,timestamp以外に複数あり、そちらのすべてを復元したい場合、どのような記載ができますでしょうか？

> こちら複数の空白行がある場合、一か所に固まってしまいます。これらの空白行もidのまとまりを崩さないようにtimestampで昇順に並べることは可能でしょうか？

`id` が空欄のデータに何の意味があるのか不明ですが(ログデータを出力しているシステムの不備でしょう)、とりあえずは以下の様になります。

```py
dfx = df.assign(_subid = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False, sort=False, dropna=False)\
                           .apply(lambda x: x['id'].isna().cumsum()))\
        .groupby(['id', '_subid'], sort=False, dropna=False)\
        .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('timestamp', ignore_index=True))\
        .reset_index(drop=True)[df.columns]
```

Comment: こちら、カラムがid,timestamp以外に複数あり、そちらのすべてを復元したい場合、どのような記載ができますでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: 回答を修正しました。

Comment: 追加質問をいたしました。お手すきの際に対応お願いいたします。@metropolis

Comment: 再度修正(`groupby()` に `dropna=False` を追加)。

Comment: こちら複数の空白行がある場合、一か所に固まってしまいます。これらの空白行もidのまとまりを崩さないようにtimestampで昇順に並べることは可能でしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: そもそも複数の空白行がある状態がおかしいので、データを前処理する方がよいかと思います。例えば、追加の ID を振るなどです。

Answer (score 1):

「加工したいデータ」の id順 は 「元データ」の id の出現順である、との仮定で回答します。
※ pandasのバージョンが1.1.0であること

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """
id,timestamp
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:01.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:02.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:03.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:04.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:05.0000000Z
idefs,2022-12-15T00:00:06.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:07.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:08.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:09.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:10.0000000Z
aaefsd,2022-12-15T00:00:11.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:12.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:13.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:14.0000000Z
qwerty,2022-12-15T00:00:15.0000000Z
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
print(df)
#        id                 timestamp
#0    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:01+00:00
#1    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:02+00:00
#2    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:03+00:00
#3    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:04+00:00
#4   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:05+00:00
#5    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:06+00:00
#6   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:07+00:00
#7   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:08+00:00
#8   qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:09+00:00
#9   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:10+00:00
#10  aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:11+00:00
#11  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:12+00:00
#12  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:13+00:00
#13  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:14+00:00
#14  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:15+00:00

key_dict = {}
for i, v in enumerate(df["id"].drop_duplicates()):
    key_dict[v] = i + 1
    
def key(s):
    return s.map(key_dict) 

df = df.sort_values(["id", "timestamp"], key = key)
print(df)
#        id                 timestamp
#0    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:01+00:00
#1    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:02+00:00
#2    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:03+00:00
#3    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:04+00:00
#5    idefs 2022-12-15 00:00:06+00:00
#4   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:05+00:00
#6   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:07+00:00
#7   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:08+00:00
#9   aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:10+00:00
#10  aaefsd 2022-12-15 00:00:11+00:00
#8   qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:09+00:00
#11  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:12+00:00
#12  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:13+00:00
#13  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:14+00:00
#14  qwerty 2022-12-15 00:00:15+00:00
```